# Keep getting math domain error

Tags: python, math

```
import math

print ("f(x) = ax2 + bx + c")

# #Get a, b and c from user

aval = float(input("Please Enter (a) value: "))
bval = float(input("Please Enter (b) value: "))
cval = float(input("Please Enter (c) calue: "))

# #Find roots
# THIS IS WERE IT GOES WRONG

root1 = (-(bval) + math.sqrt(bval**2 - 4*aval*cval))
root2 = (-(bval) - math.sqrt(bval**2 - 4*aval*cval))

#Check discriminant

discrim = float((bval**2)-(4*aval*cval))

if float(discrim > 0):
    print ("Roots at: ",roo1,root2)

elif float(discrim == 0):
    print ("Only one real root: ", root1, root2)

else:
    print ("No real Roots.")
```

Comment: Rather than add something random, add an actual question. *at the very least* tell us what inputs you gave your program, and what **full** error message you got from it. As an added bonus, the *expected output* would be nice.

Comment: You are trying to get the square root of a negative number, hence the _math domain error_.

Comment: He's probably trying to calculate the square root of a negative number, which prompts a "Value error: math domain error".

Comment: This looks wrong: `if float(discrim > 0):`. At least it is superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said, you should call `sqrt()` only with proper values.

So better do

```
...

#Check discriminant

discrim = float((bval**2)-(4*aval*cval))

if float(discrim >= 0):
    # now it is ok to calculate the roots...
    root1 = - bval + math.sqrt(discrim)
    root2 = - bval - math.sqrt(discrim)

    if float(discrim > 0):
        print ("Roots at:", root1, root2)
    else:
        print ("Only one real root:", root1, root2)
else:
    print ("No real roots.")
```

This way we are sure we are allowed to call `sqrt`.

Answer (score 0):

You are computing `sqrt(bval**2 - 4*aval*cval)`, where all parameters in parens are user-supplied. If you input something that makes the argument negative, you get your error.